# npgsql : Selecting a null data throws exception with error "Column is Null"

Tags: postgresql, null, npgsql

I am running npgsql v3.7 with .NetCore on Ubuntu.

When I execute a select query and a cell in any row in the results is null, an exception is thrown with the error message "Column is null".

I am having to work around this by putting every column in the select clause inside a case statement which tests for NULL

```
"CASE WHEN " + fieldName + " IS NULL THEN '' ELSE " + fieldName + " END "
```

This seems a bit extreme and should not be necessary.  Has anyone else come across this.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about `ngpsql`, but just as an aside, you would usually use the `COALESCE` function to achieve what you're doing in sql (usage: `COALESCE(fieldName, '')`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are probably trying to read the column like this:

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
  reader.Next();
  var o = reader.GetString(0);   // Or any other of the Get methods on reader
  ...
}
```

This code will fail if the column contains a null, and is the expected behavior. In ADO.NET, you need to check for a null value with `reader.IsDBNull(0)` before actually getting the value. That's just how the database API works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `NULL` values are giving you errors, but you can do away with the ugly `CASE` statement in favor of using `COALESCE`:

```
"COALESCE(" + fieldName + ", '')"
```

Ideally you should make a configuration change such that `NULL` values do not cause this problem.

Comment: Many thanks to all who responded, the problem was (as Marth picked up) that I was expecting NpgsqlDataReader.GetString() to handle NULL cases.  I have now changed this to test for DBNull first. Thanks.